Hilt error from AppModule class can not be resolved
I am using Hilt in Android project, and after I added class for gps tracking I am getting an error:
ModuleProcessingStep was unable to process 'com...di.AppModule' because 'LocationTracker' could not be resolved.
LocationTracker class is there and imported.
This is AppModule:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {


    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService =
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesFusedLocationProviderClient(
        application: Application
    ): FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(application)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesLocationTracker(
        fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
        application: Application
    ): LocationTracker = DefaultLocationTracker(
        fusedLocationProviderClient = fusedLocationProviderClient,
        application = application
    )
}

And these are LocationTracker and DefaultLocationTracker
interface LocationTracker {
    suspend fun getCurrentLocation(): Location?
}

class DefaultLocationTracker(
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
    private val application: Application
) : LocationTracker {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    override suspend fun getCurrentLocation(): Location? {
        val hasAccessFineLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            application,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        val hasAccessCoarseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            application,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        val locationManager = application.getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE
        ) as LocationManager

        val isGpsEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

        if (!isGpsEnabled && !(hasAccessCoarseLocationPermission || hasAccessFineLocationPermission)) {
            return null
        }

        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.apply {
                if (isComplete) {
                    if (isSuccessful) {
                        cont.resume(result) {} // Resume coroutine with location result
                    } else {
                        cont.resume(null) {} // Resume coroutine with null location result
                    }
                    return@suspendCancellableCoroutine
                }
                addOnSuccessListener {
                    cont.resume(it) {}  // Resume coroutine with location result
                }
                addOnFailureListener {
                    cont.resume(null) {} // Resume coroutine with null location result
                }
                addOnCanceledListener {
                    cont.cancel() // Cancel the coroutine
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Was fixed by restart/invalidate caches.
